# Maven exec plugin ClassNotFoundException

Tags: java, maven

I'm using the Maven exec plugin to run a java application from the command line with the command mvn exec:java. I have specified the main class in the pom.xml and the associated dependencies.

```
<groupId>com.example.MyApp</groupId>
<artifactId>MyApp</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0</version>
<build>
  <plugins>
     <plugin>
       <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
       <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>1.2.1</version>
       <executions>
         <execution>
           <goals>
             <goal>java</goal>
          </goals>
         </execution>
       </executions>
       <configuration>
          <mainClass>com.example.myclass</mainClass>
          <arguments>
            <argument>configFile</argument>
            <argument>properties</argument>
          </arguments>
       </configuration>
     </plugin>
```

I also specify a number of dependencies...

```
<dependencies>
<dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
    <type>jar</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.example.MyLibrary</groupId>
    <artifactId>MyLibrary</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

The `MyApp` program reads a config file which is passed in as a command line argument. The config file contains the name of a class which is located in `MyLibrary`. So the class could be `com.mypackage.driver.MyClass` which is located in `MyLibrary` which is a dependency of the `MyApp` jar listed above. 
However when I try to run this I get a `ClassNotFoundException`...

Update----
I'm using the system classloader to load the classes which are passed in on the command line for the `MyApp` program

```
ClassLoader loader = ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
```

I'm thinking that this is causing the problem as it is looking for the classes on the default classpath which does not contain the dependencies.

Any hints on what I'm doing wrong here?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Are you still looking for an answer to this question?  I had the exact same issue, and finally figured it out.

You need to add **includePluginDependencies** to your configuration to make the plugin search your dependencies for the main class:

```
<configuration>
  <includePluginDependencies>true</includePluginDependencies>
  <mainClass>com.example.myclass</mainClass>
  <arguments>
    <argument>configFile</argument>
    <argument>properties</argument>
  </arguments>
</configuration>
```

See here: http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/java-mojo.html#includePluginDependencies

Comment: I have the same issue, added includePluginDependencies, still ClassNotFoundException. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Also adding includePluginDependencies the error continue to face out. The reason was "clean" goal. In my case just remove it and it works. @MaxiWu

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the dependency as dependency of the execution plugin, so the execution plugin can load the class you configured `com.example.myclass`:

```
<plugins>
 <plugin>
   <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
   <artifactId>exec-maven-plugin</artifactId>
   <version>1.2.1</version>
   [...]
   <dependencies>
     <dependency>
       <groupId>com.example.MyLibrary</groupId>
       <artifactId>MyLibrary</artifactId>
       <version>1.0.0</version>
       <type>jar</type>
     </dependency>

 </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I've added the dependency to the plugin, but it's still giving me a classnotfound error. I've followed this example here http://mojo.codehaus.org/exec-maven-plugin/examples/example-exec-using-plugin-dependencies.html

Answer (score 1):

You can let the classpath get generated like this:

```
    <configuration>
      <executable>java</executable>
      <arguments>
        <argument>-Dmyproperty=myvalue</argument>
        <argument>-classpath</argument>
        <!-- automatically creates the classpath using all project dependencies,
             also adding the project build directory -->
        <classpath/>
        <argument>com.example.Main</argument>
        ...
      </arguments>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: Hi @Moritz can you elaborate further on this, I was under the impression that once I ran mvn exec:java then the dependencies that were defined by this project would automatically be included on the classpath...

Comment: Where do you put this? Inside the `<plugin>`?

Comment: yep, this is the config of the plugin

Answer (score 0):

Before to execute from command line, you should import also in command line your library. You can use this command with your expecific name and info of your library:

```
mvn install:install-file -Dfile=MyLibrary.jar -DgroupId=com.example.MyLibrary -DartifactId=MyLibrary -Dversion=1.0.0 -Dpackaging=jar
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the response, the jar is located in my local repository already

Answer (score 0):

Try `mvn clean compile exec:java`

Sometimes we forget to compile the code and when you run `mvn exec:java` without compiling, then obviously maven cannot find the compiled class files and complain about `ClassNotFoundException`